# Time-Dependant Workflow workaround for ContentVersion

Tags: workflow, scheduled-apex, bestpractice, time-dependent-workflow

What's the best way to mimic a time-dependant workflow for objects (in this case ContentVersion) that don't allow Workflows.

I've considered Scheduled Apex but am concerned about limits.

Comment: dan appleman advanced apex chapter 7 3rd edition has a pattern for unlimited scalability using queueables and a custom asyncRequest__c object. The custom object can contain a `datetime-to-be-executed-field` that the queuable engine examines and decides whether to execute or not

Comment: Also check out Doug Ayers chatter bot for files that basically enables running process builder on contentVersion, via a custom object.  https://www.google.com/amp/s/douglascayers.com/2016/12/18/chatter-bot-for-files-notify-followers-when-file-updated/amp/